# Error in seq.int(r1$mon, 12 (to0$year - r1$year) + to0$mon, by) : from must be a finite number

Tags: r, ggplot2, lubridate

I am a beginner at R studio and I am getting an error every time I run this particular code using my own data. I have formatted my own data the same way the csv is set up in the example.

The code has been taken from https://benalexkeen.com/creating-a-timeline-graphic-using-r-and-ggplot2/ (I tried to make a reprex but there were errors I didn't understand)

When I run the original code with the original data in r I still get the same errors and I am not sure what to do or how I would go about fixing it

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please share: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example + the exact code you were running (not just a link to a website)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code on the website doesn't run as expected because it reads in a file called `milestones.csv`, which you won't have access to.  However, if you actually make the dataset in `df`, everything on the website runs as expected.  The code below runs produces the expected plot.  Can you post the error you get when you try to run this code?

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~month,   ~year,  ~milestone,     ~status,
  6,    2017,   "Milestone 1",  "Complete",
  7,    2017,   "Milestone 2",  "   Complete",
  10,   2017,   "Milestone 3",  "Complete",
  12,   2017,   "Milestone 4",  "   Complete",
  1,    2018,   "Milestone 5",  "Complete",
  1,    2018,   "Milestone 6",  "   Complete",
  2,    2018,   "Milestone 7",  "Complete",
  5,    2018,   "Milestone 8",  "Complete",
  6,    2018,   "Milestone 9",  "On Target",
  6,    2018,   "Milestone 10",  "On Target",
  9,    2018,   "Milestone 11",     "At Risk",
  11,   2018,   "Milestone 12",  "On Target",
  12,   2018,   "Milestone 13",     "On Target",
  12,   2018,   "Milestone 14",  "On Target",
  12,   2018,   "Milestone 15",     "At Risk",
  4,    2019,   "Milestone 16",  "Critical",
  7,    2019,   "Milestone 17",     "On Target",
  7,    2019,   "Milestone 18",  "On Target",
  9,    2019,   "Milestone 19",     "On Target",
  10,   2019,   "Milestone 20",  "At Risk",
  10,   2019,   "Milestone 21",     "On Target",
  12,   2019,   "Milestone 22",  "Critical",
)



df$date <- with(df, ymd(sprintf('%04d%02d%02d', year, month, 1)))
df <- df[with(df, order(date)), ]
head(df)



status_levels <- c("Complete", "On Target", "At Risk", "Critical")
status_colors <- c("#0070C0", "#00B050", "#FFC000", "#C00000")

df$status <- factor(df$status, levels=status_levels, ordered=TRUE)

positions <- c(0.5, -0.5, 1.0, -1.0, 1.5, -1.5)
directions <- c(1, -1)

line_pos <- data.frame(
  "date"=unique(df$date),
  "position"=rep(positions, length.out=length(unique(df$date))),
  "direction"=rep(directions, length.out=length(unique(df$date)))
)

df <- merge(x=df, y=line_pos, by="date", all = TRUE)
df <- df[with(df, order(date, status)), ]

text_offset <- 0.05

df$month_count <- ave(df$date==df$date, df$date, FUN=cumsum)
df$text_position <- (df$month_count * text_offset * df$direction) + df$position

month_buffer <- 2

month_date_range <- seq(min(df$date) - months(month_buffer), max(df$date) + months(month_buffer), by='month')
month_format <- format(month_date_range, '%b')
month_df <- data.frame(month_date_range, month_format)

year_date_range <- seq(min(df$date) - months(month_buffer), max(df$date) + months(month_buffer), by='year')
year_date_range <- as.Date(
  intersect(
    ceiling_date(year_date_range, unit="year"),
    floor_date(year_date_range, unit="year")
  ),  origin = "1970-01-01"
)
year_format <- format(year_date_range, '%Y')
year_df <- data.frame(year_date_range, year_format)

timeline_plot<-ggplot(df,aes(x=date,y=0, col=status, label=milestone))
timeline_plot<-timeline_plot+labs(col="Milestones")
timeline_plot<-timeline_plot+scale_color_manual(values=status_colors, labels=status_levels, drop = FALSE)
timeline_plot<-timeline_plot+theme_classic()

# Plot horizontal black line for timeline
timeline_plot<-timeline_plot+geom_hline(yintercept=0, 
                                        color = "black", size=0.3)

# Plot vertical segment lines for milestones
timeline_plot<-timeline_plot+geom_segment(data=df[df$month_count == 1,], aes(y=position,yend=0,xend=date), color='black', size=0.2)

# Plot scatter points at zero and date
timeline_plot<-timeline_plot+geom_point(aes(y=0), size=3)

# Don't show axes, appropriately position legend
timeline_plot<-timeline_plot+theme(axis.line.y=element_blank(),
                                   axis.text.y=element_blank(),
                                   axis.title.x=element_blank(),
                                   axis.title.y=element_blank(),
                                   axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
                                   axis.text.x =element_blank(),
                                   axis.ticks.x =element_blank(),
                                   axis.line.x =element_blank(),
                                   legend.position = "bottom"
)

# Show text for each month
timeline_plot<-timeline_plot+geom_text(data=month_df, aes(x=month_date_range,y=-0.1,label=month_format),size=2.5,vjust=0.5, color='black', angle=90)
# Show year text
timeline_plot<-timeline_plot+geom_text(data=year_df, aes(x=year_date_range,y=-0.2,label=year_format, fontface="bold"),size=2.5, color='black')
# Show text for each milestone
timeline_plot<-timeline_plot+geom_text(aes(y=text_position,label=milestone),size=2.5)
timeline_plot
```

Comment: Thank you! I've run the above code and it works fine except for this warning at the bottom
    Warning message:
    Removed 3 rows containing missing values (geom_point).

Comment: This is because there are three missing values in the `status` variable and `ggplot` is just telling you that it can't plot those values.  Unless you assumed that there should be no missing data, you could disregard that warning.  And, you'll notice that you do get the desired plot.

Comment: Yeah I went to go enter the data into the format in your example and I then found I had not entered a month which was what was causing all the errors in the first place. I fixed that and ran the code again and it worked absolutely fine. Thank you so much for all your help with this!!